# focus on current record selected

Tags: sql, vba

i am working on a dynamic database which must be extremely professional and user friendly for the "non-access" users..

I am not sure if any code exists for this or if it is capable but I need to put a focus or highlight the record in a form (in a table type view) to emphasise with great details that the user is currently on that record.  the little Arrow on the record selector is not enough.

My first choice is that the record currently beign used remains in black colour or perhaps even enlarges whicle the other records in the rows (above and below) are greyed or faded so that it is blatently obvious that they are not selected but are available.

I would greatly appreicate any advice..
Thanks

Comment: Can you use forms instead ? "Non-access users" pretty much forces you to use forms. If that is the case then it's easy to display only one record at a time.

Comment: Yes i am using forms for the data entry..   The challenge is that i want to use a continuous form so that the other records are visible but are "greyed out" so that the user knows that they exists, could select one of them if he wanted to hower knows that at the current moment, they are not selected.

Comment: (the reason for this requirement is due to the fact that below this form (which resembles a table) there is another form linked to this form so that on every record change, the records below change accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled ['access forms change current row indicator'](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-GB&q=access%20forms%20change%20current%20row%20indicator) and the first result was http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0047.htm which looks pretty good (although maybe not very supportable). 
The problem with what you want to do is that Access doesn't do that easily; Access does a lot of things for you at the price of accepting the way it does them. When you want to change that you will have problems.

Cheers -